# get type of object under prototype function

Tags: javascript, object, typeof, prototype-programming

somebody know how to get typeof object under prototype property? i.e. I have the next code:

```
Object.prototype.someproperty = function(){
...do something...
console.log(typeof this); 
..more...
}
```

in my code this results alway's  "Function" because the constructor of objects is a function. when I call like this

```
Array.someproperty(); //In this i want get "array"
//or
String.someproperty(); //In this i want get "string"
```

I want get "Array" instead "function"... somebody know how?

Comment: typeof [] will always return "object" because all arrays are objects (in JavaScript).  A better way to check for an array is -- `Object.prototype.toString.call(yourVariableHere) === '[object Array]'`

Comment: i have solved my problem with simple "name" like this.

    Object.prototype.myfn= function(){
     return this.name;
    }
    String.myfn(); //return "String"
    Array.myfn(); //return "Array"
    Function.myfn(); //return "Function"
    Object.myfn(); //return "Object"
    Number.myfn(); //return "Number"

I change the "someproperty" by "myfn" by the controversy. Thanx guys.

Comment: Ugh, once again, you're only applying `myfn` to Functions! If that's your intent, you should extend `Function.prototype` instead of `Object.prototype`. There are very real reasons for this. Also, if you need full browser support, `.name` on a function is a non standard property, and won't work in some browsers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally along this time and with a lot of reading and learning, I have seen that it is very bad practice to extend the prototype objects. I thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `this` when called via `Array` and `String` is bound to the function and not an instance of the types.  The only way I know of to determine which of these functions is being called is to do manual testing like the following

```
Object.prototype.someproperty = function() {
  if (this === Array) {
    return "array";
  } else if (this === String) {
    return "string";
  } 
  ...
}
```

In this case though you're not actually reporting the type of the object the prototype is being invoked from.  The value "function" is quite accurate for that.  This is more of a heuristic than a true type test

Comment: It would be an improvement to extend `Function.prototype` instead if this is what OP actually wants to do.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ possibly. I'm not 100% sure what the intent of the OP was here.  My initial reaction was they wanted a function that worked on all instances but then were confused why uses on the `Array` and `String` constructor function failed. If that was the case then the extension on `Object` makes more sense.  Overall though this type of test seems doomed to be flaky at best

Comment: Yeah, this is confusing, especially since the method is named `someproperty`. But either way, IMO `Object.prototype` extensions (well enumerable ones anyway) rarely if ever make sense. But if that's what OP wants, then that's what OP gets. ;)

Comment: yep, i want extend all objects; strings,arrays,functions with a universal function for extend all types. example: <code>Array.mynewextendfn('nameoffn',function(){});</code> and add the nameoffn in a array of registre. is so rare, but for my project is important. thanx

Comment: Finally along this time and with a lot of reading and learning, I have seen that it is very bad practice to extend the prototype objects. I thank you all for your support.